# Sagemaker: MemoryError: Unable to allocate ___for an array with shape ___ and data type float64

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, memory, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a notebook in sagemaker and it seems like one of the arrays produced after vectorizing text is causing issues.

Reading other answers it seems like it is an issue with [overcommit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting). And one of the solutions proposed is to set it to always overcommit with this:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Is there any documentation or do you have any suggestion on how to do the same thing in sagemaker?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Open a root shell by `sudo -i` and then run the `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`

Answer (score -2):

Changing the default kernel in the SageMaker Notebook to conda_python3 resolved this issue for me.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). From Review.